# How to create partitioned hive table on dynamic hdfs directories

Tags: hadoop, hive, create-table, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I am having difficulty in getting hive to discover partitions which are created in HDFS

Here's the directory structure in HDFS

```
warehouse/database/table_name/A
warehouse/database/table_name/B
warehouse/database/table_name/C
warehouse/database/table_name/D
```

A,B,C,D being values from a column `type`

when I create a hive table using the following syntax

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
table_name(`name` string, `description` string) 
PARTITIONED BY (`type` string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat' 
LOCATION 'hdfs:///tmp/warehouse/database/table_name'
```

I am unable to see any records when I query the table.

But when I create directories in HDFS as below

```
warehouse/database/table_name/type=A
warehouse/database/table_name/type=B
warehouse/database/table_name/type=C
warehouse/database/table_name/type=D
```

It works and discovers partitions when I check using `show partitions table_name`

Is there some configuration in hive to able to detect dynamic directories as partitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating external table on top of some directory is not enough, partitions needs to be mounted also. [Discover partitions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-DiscoverPartitions) feature added in Hive 4.0.0. Use [MSCK REPAIR TABLE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)) for earlier versions:

```
MSCK [REPAIR] TABLE table_name [ADD/DROP/SYNC PARTITIONS];
```

or it's equivalent on EMR:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RECOVER PARTITIONS;
```

And when you creating dynamic partitions using `insert overwrite`, partition metadata is being created automatically and partition folders are in the form `key=value`.